# multipule actions if statement in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create a multipule action if statement, for example this is my script now:

```
      if (document.getElementById("username").value==null || document.getElementById("username").value=="") 
{
            alert("username must be filled out");
            return false;
}
```

and I want that in the same time as the alert pops up to add another action like change to path to some image or something llike that..

anyone know how to do this?

thanks,
Lian

Comment: You can shorten your condition to `if (!document.getElementById("username").value)`.

Comment: Just add the appropriate code before calling `alert()`.

Comment: can you show me exaple?

Comment: I don't know what kind of action you like to perform.

Comment: in addition to the alert add document.getElementById("MyFrame").src="www.google.com"

Comment: What's happening when you add this line before the `alert()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alert popup in browsers is a kind of modal form.

From the moment you call the alert, user interaction with the browser is limited to the popup buttons and you cannot do anything else.

You can't offer the user "multiple actions" with an alert popup.

Comment: and I can't add the other action before the alert or after the user clicks "ok"?

Comment: Yes, you can add actions in javascript before or after the alert() instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your own modal box as your message box.
because once you pop up an alert in js the code below will not executed unless you hit the ok button